# Yii throwing URL CException on every request

Tags: php, curl, amazon-ec2, yii

I have a Web application setup on EC2 using Yii framework. When I transfer my files on EC2 instance I am getting this error

```
CException

The URL pattern "<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>" for route "<controller>/view" is not a valid regular expression.

/var/www/html/framework/web/CUrlManager.php(700)
```

my URL rules in main.php are

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
```

I have a controller named as "ApiController.php" in controllers folder. On my local machine it works fine but the problem is on EC2 instance.

These are the some config in main.php

```
'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'AppName',
    'defaultController'=>'Api',
```

Comment: can you tell me the type of url that is generating this url? even if it is all kinds, it'll help to get an example

Comment: I tried to access this http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/ and then this http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/api/index and Please see the update in my question and see if you can help

Comment: ok, do you have a root url that needs no urlmanagement for this **app** (in the yii sense)?, i mean since this is some sort of api, do you have a browser accessible root url for it? if yes, then does that root url work without problems?

Comment: Yeah I have browser accessible url for it like a public ip associated with EC2 instance. And accessing the root url gives same error like all others

Comment: i just got this problem myself, solved it with a restart! you can check [my posts in this forum topic](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/33681-error-with-curlmanager/) to understand how i arrived at the restart!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question using this as the .htaccess removes the error

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```